# How do I turn a string into a unicode from a text file?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
Guadalajara
Culiacán
Juárez
Ecatepec
```

I want to convert all of these to unicode. I tried using:

```
unicode(INSERT WORD FROM TEXT FILE)
```

But I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there anyway of converting a string from a text file to unicode?

Comment: try using `unicode(text, 'utf-16')`

Comment: For this solution, I got the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 14: truncated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the file's encoding. If you do, open the file with `codecs.open()` and you'll automatically get proper Unicode objects:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("myfile.txt", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    text = infile.read()
```

You can also open the file "normally" and then manually decode its contents - you still need to know what the encoding is, though:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as infile:
    text = infile.read()
uni = text.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: For both of these solutions, I got the same error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 7: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @ragnampiza: As I said, you need to *know* the encoding of your file. That file is not UTF-8, then. Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings for the correct parameter to pass in `encoding="..."`.

Comment: How do you mean "know" the encoding? It's a standard text file.

Comment: Have you looked at the link? There are hundreds of ways to encode text files, some more prevalent than others, but it's nearly impossible to reliably guess the encoding from just looking at the file. You need to know which encoding was used by the program that wrote the file. In Unix, UTF-8 is pretty standard, in Windows, `cp1252` is a good bet...

Comment: Ahh yes it is cp1252

Comment: @ragnampiza: 1- [use `io.open()` instead of `codecs.open()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0400/) (the usage is the same in this case).  2- btw, if you omit the encoding then `io.open()` uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` by default (it might be `cp1252` in your case).